# How to check how many of the last elements in a list are equal in python?

Tags: python, list

I am appending integers to a list one by one (using a loop) as so:

`A.append(x)` where x is an integer, which eventually gives for example:

```
A = [4, 8, 2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 7]
```

During every loop, i.e. just after each integer is added to the end of the array, I would like to check whether the same integer has been added a certain number of times (say, 3, in the example below) and throw an exception if so.

Pseudo code:

```
if somewayofcheckingA == 3:
    raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

I could just do the below, but if I wanted to check for say, 100 repeats, then obviously the code would become a mess.

```
if A[-1] == A[-2] and A[-2] == A[-3]:
    raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "the _most recent_ appended integers"? How many of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a list to `set()` will return a set with all unique values in the list. You can use slice notation to get a list of the last `n` values using the following

```
n = 3
if len(A) >= n and len(set(A[-n:])) == 1:
    raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Except that I was going to suggest that after extracting the recent items e.g. `recent = A[-n:]`, you then evaluate `len(recent) - len(set(recent))`. Then you can distinguish between not many elements in the set because you have fewer than `n` items on the original list, and not many elements in the set because there are duplicates.

Comment: @alaniwi an additional condition of `len(A) >= n` would probably work

Comment: Yes, fair enough. By evaluating the difference in lengths you could count the number of duplicates even if you do not have have a full `n` items, but obviously the question does not specify the requirements in enough detail to say whether this should be done.

Comment: This fires a false positive if there are two sets of duplicates, each has fewer than n elements, but together there are more than n of them.

Comment: @DYZ can you provide an example of what you're talking about? Nothing in the question talks about multiple sets of duplicates

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is so badly written that it can be misinterpreted in many ways.

Comment: Sorry @DYZ, I've rephrased it a bit hopefully that's better. Happy to hear any feedback as I'm fairly new to this forum

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to check just last 3 then this would do it.

```
limit = 3
if len(set(A[-limit:])) == 1:
    raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

Comment: you answer is same as @Iain Shelvington

Comment: I was writing the answer and didn't know if the answer was already posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use collections.Counter() to count how many times the last element appears.
For example:

```
occurrences = collections.Counter(A)
if occurrences[A[-1]] >= 3:
   raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

Or an even simpler way

```
if A.count(A[-1]) >= 3:
   raise Exception("Lots of the latest integers are similar")
```

**THIS CODE CHECK FOR OCCURRENCES OF THE LAST ELEMENT AT ANY OTHER INDEX OF THE LIST

Comment: your code not work for this `A = [7, 4, 8, 2, 4, 3, 7, 7]` for this it shoudn't throw any exception but your code will throw

Comment: Both of these solutions will perform badly on large lists, both of them will result in iterating over the entire list

Answer (score 1):

I did this for you. And I think this is some kind of pythonic.

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, seq=()):
        self.last_equal_items = []
        super().__init__(seq)

    def append(self, some_item):
        if self.last_equal_items and some_item != self.last_equal_items[-1]:
            self.last_equal_items = []
        self.last_equal_items.append(some_item)
        if len(self.last_equal_items) >= 3:
            raise ValueError("Last equal items larger that 3")
        else:
            super(CustomList, self).append(some_item)

test = CustomList([])
test.append(1)
test.append(1)
test.append(1)
test.append(2)
test.append(1)
print(test)
```

You can just use `CustomList` like `list`. And it will alert when you insert the third equal value.

Answer (score 1):

```
lists = [1,4,3,3];
def somewayofcheckingA(lists, a):
    lists.reverse()
    i = 0
    k = lists[0]
    count = 0
    while i < a:
        if(lists[i] == k):
            count= count+1
        i = i+1
    return count
        
print(test(lists, 3))
```

where lists is the list and a is the number of times you want to check

This answer is easy to follow and utilizes basic looping and conditional statements, which I think you should master before venturing into the other proposed solutions, which are more pythonic, but where you might get lost in the mix.

Comment: By calling `lists.reverse()` in your function you have modified the passed in list, this is rarely what you would ever want

Comment: i do agree...wrote it in the moment but could be easily restored